# How do I map the `/users/sign_up` path to `/users/new`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to "use" the `/users/sign_up` PATH instead of `/users/new` in order to register new users to my application.

How can I make that "a là Ruby on Rails Way"?

---

*Note*: at this time I am using the following code in the `routes.rb` file but I think it isn't the best way to accomplish that I am looking for:

```
resources :users, :except => [:new] do
  collection do
    get 'sign_up'
  end
end
```

What would you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
resources :users, :path_names => {:new => 'sign_up'}
```

Its in the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
match '/users/sign_up' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
```

and make links with the `signup_path` helper method